# Checking words in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-arguments

I need to search for the exact word and have it not include words inside a word if that makes sense, I am stumped

UPDATE:
Tried using regex still producing similar results, used re match but produced 
all words as incorrect

File of incorrect words:
dis is my spel cheker program

File of correct words:
this is my spell checker program

```
word = ""
    with open(sys.argv[1],"r") as fh: 
        while True:
            ch=fh.read(1)
            if ch == " " or ch == "\n" or ch == ":" or ch == ".":
                with open(sys.argv[2],"r") as fh2:
                    def check_word(word,fh2):
                        lines = fh2.readlines()
                        for line in lines:
                            x= re.match(word,line)
                            if x:
                                print(word + ": " + "0")
                                #count += 1
                            else:
                                print(word, ": " , "1")
                                #count2 += 1   
                    check_word(word,fh2)
                word = ''
            else:
                word += ch
            if not ch:
                print(word)
                print("End of file")
                print(count)
                print(count2)
                break
```

Comment: Suggest you to use regex for word matching. It will be easier.

Comment: Should I use search or match? I used search and gave me same results and when I used match gave me different results, all words were produced as incorrect. Updated code above.

Comment: Can you please share data in both the files ?

Comment: Updated the post with both files. Problem I am running into is the word spell. Since I am passing spel it detects it in the word spell so assumes its correct when its not.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't understand what are you trying to do.
Based on your code I think you want to get a list with a word and how many times that  word appears in a file. I used as file the following text, in your question:

"So its basically just looking for anything within the file that matches the exact letters, so if i have the word pumpki in the first file and pumpkin in the second file it will produce results saying it is correct or been found, even though it's not correct. I need to search for the exact word and have it not include words inside a word if that makes sense, I am stumped."

```
#counting words
from collections import Counter

f = open("single.txt", "r")

word_list = [] #initiate the list

for words in f:
    counting = Counter(words.split(' '))

my_word = 'pumpkin'

for k,v in counting.items():
    if my_word == k:
        #v is the counter
        pair = (k,v)
        word_list.append(pair)

print(word_list)
#[('pumpkin', 1)]
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but that is not my task. This is a spell checker program. I am trying to validate words being correct or not based on two files, one file with incorrectly spelled words and one with the correct spelled words